# Enviar el contenido a un programa de Java y ejecutarlo

Tags: java

Quería saber si existe la forma de, a través de un formulario con html, enviar los datos introducidos por el usuario y que esos datos se reciban en un programa de Java para que se ejecute un programa con esos valores.

Actualmente el programa Java lo ejecuto introduciendo los datos a través de un JOptionPane, y me gustaría poder hacerlo desde la web. Que igual se puede hacer de otra forma, pero es la que se me ocurre.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo como hacer un servlet que capture los datos y lance el un nuevo proceso con el programa en cuestión?

Comment: puedes usar com.sun.net.httpserver, aqui hay un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api

Comment: @yorodm Si te soy sincero no sé exactamente cómo se le llama. A través de un input, quería enviar unos datos, que esos datos se reciban en el programa java en cuestión, es decir, en vez de recibirlos por JOptionPane se reciban a través del input y ejecutar el programa java.